# Ошибка UnicodeDecodeError Django3

Tags: python, django, utf-8

Имею ошибку `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 5: invalid continuation byte` при запуске `py manage.py runserver`, не знаю как с ней справиться. Смотрел похожие вопросы. Везде говорили что в имени пользователя содержится кириллица, но у меня имя пользователя-`home`. Вчера программа программа работала сервер отлично запускался, но сегодня выдаёт это.

P.S В коде у меня везде используются буквы в ascii

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка исправлена.
Оказывается, краткое имя компьютера было `home`, а полное имя, которое можно посмотреть через команду `msinfo32`, было `home-ПК`, а его можно изменить через Панель управления\Система и безопасность\Система => Дополнительные параметры системы => Имя компьютера => Изменить